# Unable to Deserialize XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have the following code but unable to deserialize, can you see where I'm going wrong? It only catch the first record on the first array item.

```
[XmlRootAttribute("Booking")]
        public class Reservation
        {
            [XmlArray("Included")]
            [XmlArrayItem("Meals")]
            public Meals[] Food { get; set; }

            [XmlArrayItem("Drinks")]
            public Drinks[] Drink { get; set; }

        }

        public class Meals
        {
            [XmlAttribute("Breakfast")]
            public string Breakfast { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("Lunch")]
            public string Lunch { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("Dinner")]
            public string Dinner { get; set; }
        }

        public class Drinks
        {
            [XmlAttribute("Soft")]
            public string Softs { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("Beer")]
            public string Beer { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("Wine")]
            public string Wine { get; set; }
        }
```

Here's the associated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Booking>
    <Included>
        <Meals  
        Breakfast="True" 
        Lunch="True" 
        Dinner="False">
        </Meals>
        <Drinks 
            Soft="True"
            Beer="False"
            Wine="False">
        </Drinks>
    </Included>
    <Included>
        <Meals  
        Breakfast="True" 
        Lunch="False" 
        Dinner="False">
        </Meals>
        <Drinks 
            Soft="True"
            Beer="True"
            Wine="True">
        </Drinks>
    </Included>
</Booking>
```

I'm a bit of a newbie so any help would be great, unfortunately after trawling through the many exmaples you already have online I still haven't been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following example and apply this syntax in `ListItem` array,

```
[XmlType("device_list")]
[Serializable]
public class DeviceList {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement( "item" )]
    public ListItem[] items { get; set; }
}
```

following link contains all the syntax & attributes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I see no obvious way your class structure could be matched to the XML document. The underlying organizations seem to be quite different.

The following class hierarchy could be easily deserialized from the XML document you provide (assuming your document covers the general case) :

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Booking")]
public class Booking : List<Included>
{
}

[Serializable]
public class Included
{
    public Meals Meals { get; set; }
    public Drinks Drinks { get; set; }
}

public class Meals
{
    [XmlAttribute("Breakfast")]
    public string Breakfast { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Lunch")]
    public string Lunch { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Dinner")]
    public string Dinner { get; set; }
}

public class Drinks
{
    [XmlAttribute("Soft")]
    public string Softs { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Beer")]
    public string Beer { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Wine")]
    public string Wine { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialization code would be : (`serializedObject` is the string containing your serialized object)

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (string));
XmlReader reader = XmlTextReader.Create(new StringReader(serializedObject));
var myBooking = ser.Deserialize(reader) as Booking;
```

Comment: @user1641194 sorry did not see your comment. Guess you figured it by now. Updated my answer anyway.